# Value of type "Entity" has no member 'text'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am making a basic note taking app. I cannot seem to change the text of my attributes in my code. Any advice?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class NoteInputTableViewController: UITableViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var listItem: List?

let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

@IBOutlet weak var inputNoteLabel: UITextField!

func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

    if let item = listItem {
        listItem.text = inputNoteLabel.text
    } else {
        let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! List
        newItem.text = inputNoteLabel.text
    }

    if let controller = viewController as? NoteHomeTableViewController {
        controller.items = [items!] 
    }
}





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.delegate = self

} // viewDidLoad end

}
```

In my navigationController I am attempting to change the text of my listItem, but cannot seem to do so.

Below is my List+CoreDataProperties.swift file:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension List {

    @NSManaged var note: String?
    @NSManaged var completionDate: NSDate?

}
```

And below is my NoteHomeTableViewController.swift file:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class NoteHomeTableViewController: UITableViewController, MyCellDelegate { // will need a delegate

var items: [List] = []

let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

@IBAction func composeButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("CellDetailSegue", sender: nil)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! NoteInputTableViewController
    if let ip = sender as? NSIndexPath {
        destination.listItem = items[ip.row]

    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell") as! MyCell

    cell.indexPath = indexPath
    cell.item = items[indexPath.row]
    cell.delegate = self


    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    performSegueWithIdentifier("CellDetailSegue", sender: indexPath)
}

func myCell(myCell: MyCell, didPressBackItem: List,
            atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let item = items[indexPath.row]
    managedObjectContext.deleteObject(item)
    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {
        print("error saving")
    }
    fetchItems()
    tableView.reloadData()

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

} // viewDidLoad end

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    fetchItems()
    tableView.reloadData()
} // viewDidAppear end

func fetchItems() {
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "List")
    items = []
    do {
        let response = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [List]
        for item in response {
            items.append(item)
            }
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching data!")
    }
} // fetch end

} // class end
```

Comment: Where's the definition of `List`?

Comment: question in not clear! provide more details like core data model, controller.items??, how you are initialising and using `NoteInputTableViewController`

Comment: @DavidBerry List is my created entity in CoreData. The attribute is 'note'(which is a string). I assume that would be the definition?

Comment: Please include the code for the `List` class in your question.  Your description of it is a bit hard to follow.  (e.g. Your comment makes it seem that you should be using `item.note` rather than `item.text` but it would be nice to see what is really in there.)

Comment: @PhillipMills I've added more details to try and explain better. I tried changing "item.text" to "item.note", which seemed to possibly work. Working through a new error to see if that did the trick. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you initialize `listItem`.

I suggest

```
} else {
  let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! List
  newItem.text = inputNoteLabel.text
}
```

should probably become

```
} else {
  let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! List
  listItem = newItem
  newItem.text = inputNoteLabel.text
}
```

Comment: I tried initializing listItem as you mentioned, but still see the error. Would I need to initialize it before the else statement? Thanks!

Comment: If I understand you view controller hierarchy, you have a navigation controller which root is a NoteHomeTableViewController. And when the user select an row of NoteHomeTableViewController, a NoteInputTableViewController is pushed. In this case, I find weird that NoteInputTableViewController is delegate of the navigation controller. It would make more sense for the root (NoteHomeTableViewController) to be the delegate. The problem is probably that `navigationController(_:, willShowViewController:, animated:)` is never called because it already happened when the NoteInput becomes delegate

Answer (score 0):

Use the unwrapped `item` after the optional binding and assign the new initialized `NSManagedObject` to `listItem`

```
...    
if let item = listItem {
    item.text = inputNoteLabel.text
} else {
    listItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! List
    listItem!.text = inputNoteLabel.text
...
```

or easier

```
...    
if listItem == nil {
    listItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! List
}
listItem!.text = inputNoteLabel.text
...
```

Comment: I tried both blocks of code, but still have the error. Do I need to unwrap item before these lines? Sorry if I'm not understanding properly.